# Reading text files with aws lambda native

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, quarkus

I have a quarkus lambda that needs to read in a couple of text files. This works fine when doing a non-native version. However when I try use a native version if can't find the files. I've added the text files to the resources and the resources/META-INF.resources folder but no luck.

The class to load them in is

```
@Component
public class ModulusWeightTableSupplier implements Supplier<List<ModulusWeightTableEntry>>{

    private static final String MODULUS_WEIGHT_TABLE = "/AccountModulus_Weight_Table.txt";

    @Override
    public List<ModulusWeightTableEntry> get(){

        final List<ModulusWeightTableEntry> modulusWeightTable = new ArrayList<>();
        try(final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(MODULUS_WEIGHT_TABLE)))){
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                final String[] fields = line.split("\\s+");
                modulusWeightTable.add(new ModulusWeightTableEntry(fields));
            }
        }
        catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new TableSupplierRuntimeException("An error occurred loading the modulus weight table or sort code substitution table", e);
        }
        return modulusWeightTable;
    }
}
```

So for some reason the native version can't find the files. I guess Im missing something that tells it to include the resources folders? Its now using a custom run-time when using the native version.

```
2020-06-07 13:15:21,940 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) HTTP Request to /bank-details-validation/v1/account-validation failed, error id: fcffa89d-efaa-4a26-859d-031cfb3ddbaf-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:216)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:515)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:259)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:160)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:362)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:163)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:245)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:123)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:36)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:87)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:167)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
        at bankdetailsvalidator.quarkus.supplier.ModulusWeightTableSupplier.get(ModulusWeightTableSupplier.java:32)
```

Comment: Since your file path is `"/AccountModulus_Weight_Table.txt"`, doesn't it search for the file in the root folder due to '/'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding external resources, you need to include them into the native image. The native image does not include resources except if you explicitly told it to.

In latest Quarkus releases, you can just use:

```
quarkus.native.resources.includes = AccountModulus_Weight_Table.txt
```

or even:

```
quarkus.native.resources.includes = *.txt
```

or (`**/*.txt` with a glob)

In older versions, you would have to do something like: https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#including-resources .